# After adding the Where clause in CakePHP QueryBuild i get a general error

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP 5.0
PHP 8.2.11

I have a SQLite database with one record.
The select statement shows the record whiteout problem
but wen i add the where statement i get a error.
Is this a bug or am i missing something?

I only the QueryBuild from CakePHP.

The code below reproduce the error every time
Column `id` is the primary-key.

```php
private function getCakeByName()
{
    $conn = new \Cake\Database\Connection([
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlite',
        'database' => '/var/www/db/users.sqlite.db'
    ]);

    $qf = new \App\Factory\Query\CakeQueryFactory($conn);
    $query = $qf->newSelect('Users');
    $query = $query->select('*');
    $row = $query->execute()->fetch('assoc');
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($row);
    echo '</pre>' . "\n";

    $query1 = $qf->newSelect('Users');
    $query1 = $query1->select('*');
    $query1 = $query1->where(['username' => 'ed']);
    $row = $query1->execute()->fetch('assoc');

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($row);
    echo '</pre>' . "\n";
    die('the end');
}
```

The result for the first dump

```php
array(5) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["username"]=>
  string(2) "ed"
  ["password"]=>
  string(60) "$2y$10$/g6vWcQov4lymHW5.iV3tOmwR2OXFSx9OxenMALSye3mOci4i4m2W"
  ["email"]=>
  string(25) "John@example.com"
  ["role"]=>
  string(4) "user"
}
```

The error while running the execute with the where statement

```php
PDOException HY000
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 column index out of range
/var/www/vendor/cakephp/database/Statement/Statement.php Line 159
```

Need more info then please let me know.